# What is the difference between Transform and transform in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I know Transform is used to get position, rotation and scale of an gameobject but what does transform do?

```
{
    public Transform player;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = player.position;
    }

}
```

here Transform gets the position, rotation and scale and then stores it in the variable player. I also understand that from the line "transform.position" that it is used to convert the position to player position but is that the only use and am I right about this?

Comment: I guess `Transform` is a type, and `transform` is a variable (i.e. an instance) of that type.

Answer (score 0):

`Transform` is a type, and is described in the Unity Documentation as

> Position, rotation and scale of an object.
> Every object in a Scene has a Transform. It's used to store and
> manipulate the position, rotation and scale of the object. Every
> Transform can have a parent, which allows you to apply position,
> rotation and scale hierarchically. This is the hierarchy seen in the
> Hierarchy pane.

Every C# script that inherits `MonoBehaviour` in Unity will have a transform. Inherting `MonoBehaviour` will allow for a script to be *attached* to a `GameObject` in Unity. The `MonoBehaviour` class has many fields, one of them is the `transform` field, which has the type of `Transform`. The Unity Documentation describes the field as

> The Transform attached to this GameObject.

Every `GameObject` has a `Transform` component, meaning that every Unity script using `MonoBehaviour` will have a non-null field called transform.

If your script is attached to the player `GameObject`, then there would be no need for you to store a reference to the player, and could instead use the transform variable.

Answer (score 0):

`Transform` is a class in UnityEngine while `transform` is a property of type `Transform` from the `GameObject` attached to the script.